# Is this platinum ore?

Tags: rocks, ore

Was found in central Mexico. It's very metallic, shiny, showing some streaks of gold and quartz.

[image]

Comment: No, this is not platinum ore.

Comment: How dense is it? My first guess ore part is galena (lead sulphide). The golden looking mineral is either pyrite (fool's gold) or chalcopyrite. Quartz-looking mineral can also be calcite, you can check it with acid.

Comment: Good question. It looks a little bit like silver to me.

Comment: Please read this https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions

Comment: Probably not. Pt is known to occur in alluvial deposits, Nickel deposits or rather even, Chromitites like at the Bushveld Igneous complex. It can occur with gold. That's not visible gold.

Answer (score 3):

The rock you have is most likely not platinum ore.  It appears to be sulfide ore most likely composed of galena, pyrite, and maybe copper sulfides such as bornite.

It is more likely that your specimen is silver ore rather than platinum ore.
Mexico has a long history of silver mining.

There is a platinum deposit in southern mexico and it appears to similar to the Bushveld igneous complex deposit.  Ref: [Mindat](https://www.mindat.org/loc-132658.html).

Layered chromtite ore looks significantly different.  [Reference](https://www.geologyforinvestors.com/layered-mafic-intrusions-largest-source-platinum-palladium/).
[image]

[USGS report on Platiunum](https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/commodity/platinum/myb1-2012-plati.pdf)
[Article on current silver mining in Mexico.](https://www.mining-technology.com/features/feature-the-10-biggest-silver-mines-in-the-world/)